# average total orders per hour

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I try to make an query that shows the average total orders per hour over a period.

I try it like this:

```
SELECT [day], 
       [hour], 
       [dayn], 
       Avg(totals) AS [Avg] 
FROM   (SELECT [document no_] AS hallo, 
               Cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR, [shipment date], 101) AS DATE), 
               w = Datediff(week, 0, [timestamp]), 
               [Day] = Datename(weekday, [timestamp]), 
               [DayN] = Datepart(weekday, [timestamp]), 
               [Hour] = Datepart(hour, [timestamp]), 
               Totals = Count(*) 
        FROM   [verploegen poc$sales line] 
        WHERE  [shipment date] BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31' 
          AND ( [document no_] NOT LIKE '%RET%' 
                AND [document no_] NOT LIKE '%OFF%' 
                AND [document no_] NOT LIKE '%CV%' 
                AND [document no_] NOT LIKE '%RC%' ) 
        GROUP  BY [document no_], 
                  [shipment date], 
                  Datediff(week, 0, [timestamp]), 
                  Datename(weekday, [timestamp]), 
                  Datepart(weekday, [timestamp]), 
                  Datepart(hour, [timestamp])) AS hallo 
GROUP  BY [day], 
          [hour], 
          [dayn] 
ORDER  BY dayn;
```

But I get the error:

> No column name was specified for column 2 of 'hallo'.

But how to correct this?

Thank you

I have it now like this:

```
SELECT [Day], [Hour], [DayN], AVG(Totals) AS [Avg]
FROM
(
    SELECT [Document No_] as hallo,  cast(CONVERT(varchar, [Shipment Date], 101) as date) as number,   
  w = DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, [timestamp]),
      [Day]  = DATENAME(WEEKDAY, [timestamp]),
      [DayN] = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [timestamp]),
      [Hour] = DATEPART(HOUR,    [timestamp]),
      Totals = COUNT(*)
    FROM [Verploegen POC$Sales Line]
     WHERE [Shipment Date] BETWEEN '2016-01-01' and '2016-12-31'
AND ([Document No_] NOT LIKE '%RET%' AND [Document No_] NOT LIKE  '%OFF%'
AND [Document No_] NOT LIKE '%CV%' AND [Document No_]  NOT LIKE '%RC%')
    GROUP BY 
    [Document No_], [Shipment Date],
  DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, [timestamp]),
      DATENAME(WEEKDAY, [timestamp]),
      DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [timestamp]),
      DATEPART(HOUR,    [timestamp])
  ) AS hallo 
GROUP BY [Day], [Hour], [DayN]
ORDER BY DayN;
```

But I get this error:

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.
```

Comment: Name this column  `cast(CONVERT(varchar, [Shipment Date], 101) as date)`

Comment: Give a column name SELECT [Document No_] as hallo,  cast(CONVERT(varchar, [Shipment Date], 101) as date) as ColX,

Comment: What is the difference between `[Day]` and `[DayN]`

Answer (score 1):

You have to alias columns in subqueries so that you can reference them later.

```
cast(CONVERT(varchar, [Shipment Date], 101) as date) as whatYouNameIt
```

The above line needs to have a column alias so that you can reference it with `hallo.whatYouNameIt`

Comment: You atleast give a damn name to that column ;)